# Django filtering with OR condition

Tags: django, filter, conditional-statements

I have a Models.py declared thus

```
class Age(models.Model):
    ageChoices=(
        ('Child', 'Child'),
        ('Adult', 'Adult'),
        ('Old', 'Old'),
    )
    age = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=ageChoices)
    class Meta: 
        verbose_name_plural='1. Age'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.age

class Gender(models.Model):
    genderChoices=(
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female'),
        ('Others', 'Others'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=genderChoices)
    class Meta: 
        verbose_name_plural='2. Gender'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.gender

class Images(models.Model):
    title =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age=models.ForeignKey(Age, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender=models.ForeignKey(Gender, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is the filters.py file

```
class ImagesFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    age = ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Age.objects.all(),widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    gender = ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Gender.objects.all(),widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = [ 'age', 'gender']
```

My views.py is defined like this:

```
def images(request):
    imagelist = Images.objects.all()
    imageFilter = ImagesFilter(request.GET,queryset=imagelist)
    print (request.GET)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'filter': imageFilter})
```

My template is like this

```
<form method="get">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ filter.form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<ul>
   {% for item in filter.qs %}
       <li>{{ item.title }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

There are two images with these properties for example
Image 0001: Child, Male
Image 0002: Old, Female

In the filter appearing on the rendered template, if I choose "child", then Image 0001 appears.
If I choose "Female", with "child" filter selected, I would like to have both images displayed. (Basically OR condition). What is now given is an AND condition, and so with "Female" and "Child" filters applied, I get no images.

How can I modify my code to bring OR functionality? Searching on the net gives OR functionality over combining querysets with OR (|) but I am not sure how this can be applied to my case.

I would also like to have the template rendered with the selection fields made available within individual forms. Is it possible?

[image: Current Rendering]

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

The simple way from a coding point of view wuld be to use exclusion filters. I've never done this with `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` but try

```
class ImagesFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    age =  ModelMultipleChoiceFilter( exclude=True, label="Exclude ages", 
               queryset=Age.objects.all(),widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    gender = ModelMultipleChoiceFilter( exclude=True, label="Exclude Genders", 
               queryset=Gender.objects.all(),widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = [ 'age', 'gender']
```

Otherwise you are into `method=my_method`, and define my_method, which will use Django Q objects combined with the `|` or operator. No experience with ModelMultipleChoice, so won't attempt to guess the code details!

Comment: 1. I needed the ModelMultipleChoiceFilter for rendering the filter options as a checkbox; otherwise they were rendered by default as a dropdown menu
2. The solution you gave has been tried, but didnt work with my setup. Thanks anyways

Comment: I am getting a "unexpected keyword argument exclude" error, when I tried with AgeFilter instead of ModelMultipleChoiceFilter

Comment: Pass. The doc says `exclude` can be applied to any filter. https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#keyword-only-arguments